# Change dimensions of multiple objects the same amount

Tags: mesh, objects

so I made a fractured circle with the cell fracture add on, but between the fractures of all the pieces I want an equidistant space between them. Favorably a solution where I can fill in an exact number.

now I have tried to use the scale option on multiple objects, with alt scale, but that results in the following.

[image: when using the scale option on multiple objects]

when I do this, I have the problem that the bigger pieces do not proportionally scale to the smaller pieces and vice versa, the result being that they all have different spaces between them.

does anyone have a solution for me?

update 1:

so what I've tried to do is get the inner edges of the fragments merge them by distance, made them a bit bigger then the circle, convert to curve, then added a plane that I converted into a curve as well, and added the plane curve as an object bevel in the object data properties, resulting in the following.

[image]

now the question if there is a fast way to make these all connect to each other so I can use this as a cutter for the circle.

Comment: i might not be right, but i think what you are asking for is mathematically impossible. I think you cannot have the same spaces between all pieces and proportionally scale them in this fractured cell scenario.

Comment: Its just that I want all the objects be 0,5 mm smaller in both directions. So there is a 1 mm gap between all the parts everywhere. I dont want to scale them, scaling causes the issue im having with the different gap sizes everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the top off your fragments, <kbd>I</kbd> inset faces, invert the selection, delete, and re-extrude to thickness. But with all the acute angles, the inset's likely to create quite a mess to clean up.

Here's a GN group that does it with a mesh-boolean. It does return a single object from a collection of fragments, but they could be separated again, by loose parts, if wanted.

[image]

I found the result was cleaner if the boolean was executed on the top surface alone, and the result re-solidified. That's why the apparently unnecessary nodes are there.

[image]

I guess you may want to leave the external perimeter untouched? Call back if so. There will be a way, I'm sure.

[image] Blender 3.2b

Comment: Since I'm still lacking knowledge on geometry nodes, I went with another approach (see update) that gives me a little more control over what I do, albeit more manual. thank you for showing me though

Comment: That's fine, you can always just download the file and use the GN modifier on your fragment collection :)